# localization and tensor product of algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, schemes

Let $A,B, C$ be commutative rings. Let $i: A \rightarrow B$ and $j : A \rightarrow C$ be ring homomorphisms. Now, let $p$ be a prime ideal in $ B \otimes_A C$. Let $f$ be canonical map from $B$ to $ B \otimes_A C$ and $g$ be the canonical map from $C$ to $ B \otimes_A C$. Let $q$ be the inverse image of $p$ in $A$.

What is the relation between $ (B \otimes_A C)_p$ and $B_{f^{-1}(p)} \otimes_{A_q} C_{g^{-1}(p)}$? Is $ (B \otimes_A C)_p$ is isomorphic to $(B_{f^{-1}(p)} \otimes_{A_q} C_{g^{-1}(p)})_{p'}$? Here $p'$ is the inverse image of $p$ in $B_{f^{-1}(p)} \otimes_{A_q} C_{g^{-1}(p)}$ ( There is a canonical map from $B_{f^{-1}(p)} \otimes_{A_q} C_{g^{-1}(p)}$ to  $ (B \otimes_A C)_p$).

I can show that there exists canonical maps using the universal property from $a: B \otimes_A C  \rightarrow B_{f^{-1}(p)} \otimes_{A_q} C_{g^{-1}(p)}$ and $b:  B_{f^{-1}(p)} \otimes_{A_q} C_{g^{-1}(p)} \rightarrow  (B \otimes_A C)_p$ such that composition of $a$ and $b$ is canonical map from  $ B \otimes_A C$ to $(B \otimes_A C)_p$. Using this I can show this is an injective map from $(B \otimes_A C)_p$ to $(B_{f^{-1}(p)} \otimes_{A_q} C_{g^{-1}(p)})_{p'}$. But I don't know how to prove it is surjective. ( I'm not even sure if that is true).

Comment: Can you prove your two rings are isomorphic by defining ring homomorphisms in both directions which are inverses to each other?  In one direction I want to use the canonical map you mentioned.  In the other direction, I want to use the canonical map B \otimes_A C -> B_{f^-1(p)} \otimes_{A_q} C_{g^-1(p)}.  If those really do define maps, then I think you can show that the two compositions are the identity maps.

Comment: I edited my question. I can show one direction (injectivity). I'm not able to convince myself surjectivity also holds.